# How to count all non-blank cells using Excel Javascript Addins?

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-js, office-addins

I'm creating an office js addin that inserts data from the bottom of Table 1 into Table 2 but I am unable to find a method of doing this that works.

I have tried using `Excel.Functions.countA()` but I can't seem to get a value other than *NaN* out of it. Here is the code I'm using:

```js
async function run() {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async context => {

      var sheet1Name = "Sheet1";
      var sheet1RangeAddress = "B:B";
      var sheet2Name = "Sheet2";
      var sheet2RangeAddress = "A2:P2";

      var sheet2Range = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheet2Name).getRange(sheet2RangeAddress);

      sheet2Range.insert("Down");

      var sheet1CellAddress = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheet1Name).getRange(sheet1RangeAddress).load("address");
      var sheet1RangeLength = Number(context.workbook.functions.countA(sheet1CellAddress));
      var sheet1LastCell = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheet1Name).getRangeByIndexes(3,1,sheet1RangeLength,1).getLastCell();

      var sheet2Cell = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheet2Name).getRange("A2");
      sheet2Cell.values = [[ context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheet2Name).getRange("A2").copyFrom(sheet1LastCell) ]]

      await context.sync();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

I can't find anything useful in Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.functions#counta-values-) or a working example online. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in your code looks problematic:

```
 var sheet1RangeLength = Number(context.workbook.functions.countA(sheet1CellAddress));
```

The `Functions.countA` method returns an [Excel.FunctionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.functionresult?view=excel-js-preview) object which I don't think can be cast to a Number. The count returned by the function will be in the `value` property of the returned object. You need to load that value to read it. Try these two lines as a replacement:

```
 var sheet1RangeLength = context.workbook.functions.countA(sheet1CellAddress).load("value");
 await context.sync();
```

BTW, the following line is returning a Range object, not an address. That's OK because countA accepts a Range object parameter, but your variable is misleadingly named. Also, I don't think the `load("address")` on the end is serving any purpose.

```
var sheet1CellAddress = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheet1Name).getRange(sheet1RangeAddress).load("address");
```

If you haven't already, please see this article: [Call built-in Excel worksheet functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-worksheet-functions).

Comment: Thank you so much for this clarification! Everything is working now!